# UCAExc:::3.0.7 Decoding not supported. Please choose a CodecProvider which supports reading the current database encoding.error

Tags: java, ucanaccess

In my project I was using .mdb file but I changed it .accdb file because of some reason. After doing this it gives me this error.

`UCAExc:::3.0.7 Decoding not supported.  Please choose a CodecProvider which supports reading the current database encoding`.

Why it gives me this error. My database connection like this.

```
    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    baglanti= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + db_file,db_username,db_password);
    sorgu = baglanti.createStatement(); 
    ResultSet gr=sorgu.executeQuery("SELECT strModule,GroupName FROM TableRun ORDER BY ID");
```

Comment: UCanAccess 3.0.7 is very old. First, try upgrading to the current version and see if your problem persists.

Comment: @GordThompson I deleted UCanAccess 3.0.7 and I added UCanAccess 4.0.4 but still gives me UCanAccess 3.0.7 error.

Comment: @GordThompson When I remove the .accdb database password, it's working correctly but when .accdb database has password, it gives me this error.

Comment: You need a `jackcessOpener` class, something like [this](https://github.com/gordthompson/ucanaccess-generic-opener).

Comment: @GordThompson Yeah, I added **jackcessOpener** class in my project and problem solved. Thanks.